# Bypassing CERT_HAS_EXPIRED leads to 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, credentials, authorization

In our Next.js app, axios requests work in client components (using `useEffect`) but fail with a `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED` error from server components. As a workaround in development, we run `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 node server.js`, based on a Stack Overflow [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433287/node-js-request-cert-has-expired). However, this leads to a 401 Unauthorized error, probably due to a cookie-stored credential required by our back end.

Could the workaround for the `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED` error cause the 401 Unauthorized issue, or are they unrelated?

Comment: Usually, fixing the certificate will resolve the issue. However, an expired certificate is expired for a reason: it has an expiration date.

Comment: @djdomi But how come I don't have that issue when I send a request from a client component? Maybe doing so doesn't require the certificate?

Comment: First, address the primary issue and then proceed to debug it if it still persists. Your Primary Workaround is to fix the Certificate in anyways... :)